# Why does mLayoutParams is null when i inflate from xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

This is the code for inflating view:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
```

And my `test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50px">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set breakpoint below this line which inflate `test.xml` and found that the `mLayoutParams` instance in view is null. I guess if specifying the parent view at the second parameter of  inflate, this won't occur.
But it still feels very strange: if `mLayoutParams` is null, so why should i set `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes in LinearLayout elements.

Comment: `http://androidforums.com/developer-101/299916-inflating-layout-xml-files-layout-parameters.html`   I found somebody has asked this question before, but no one answer it.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

or

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getLayoutInflater();

after this i think your problem will be solved.

Comment: It's my fault. I mistyped 'mLayoutParams' to 'mLayoutInflate'. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

create using following way.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I have tried using this way to instantiate inflater, but mLayoutParams is still null.